# For any cycle, must there exist a planar graph embedding with it as the face boundary?

Tags: graph-theory, planar-graphs, topological-graph-theory

For a plane graph $G$, if $C$ is a cycle in $G$, can $G$ be embedded in the plane so that $C$ is the face boundary of the outer face of $G$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not necessarily.

Given any embedding of connected $G$ in the plane, if I can find a cycle $C_1$ that is outsides of $C$ and another cycle $C_2$ that is inside of $C$, then $C$ will always have to separate these 2 other cycles, hence can never be the outer face boundary.

Comment: This only works if $C_1$ and $C_2$ belong to 'overlapping bridges' of the cycle $C$ (for a counter-example, take a tree, and add exactly 3 edges to make 3 vertex disjoint cycles embedded on concentric circles. This works for what you are saying, but you can still embed any cycle as the boundary of the outer face). As an aside, your construction will always work if $G$ is 3-connected, but not necessarily if $G$ is not.

Answer (score 2):

For a concrete example, let $G$ be the complete graph on five vertices with a single edge removed. Let $C$ be the $3$-cycle in this graph around the remaining degree $4$ vertices. If you try to embed $G$ in the plane with $C$ as the outer face, then the remaining two vertices must be embedded inside of $C$, and each must be connected to each of outer three vertices. Drawing this out, you'll notice it's impossible.